# Is SendAsync() sync if I don't do await?

Tags: c#, .net, http, asynchronous

I'm new to Web APIs. I have a basic question.

If I don't add await in front of the [`SendAsync()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.sendasync?view=net-5.0) in .NET, will it in that case be a synchronous call?

Comment: Be clear - `await` doesn't *start* anything. `SendAsync` is invoked and has *no idea* what the caller is going to do with its result when it chooses to return, including whether or not it directly or indirectly ends up using it with `await`.

Comment: No, why would it?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever OK! But I´m trying to understand what is async in such case? If I inovke SendAsync() and not giving the control back to calling method...

Comment: @kran - `await` is literally "async wait" - it waits for *something* (and it doesn't care what) and it does so whilst not blocking the current thread. A common mistake I see (and suspect you had) is people thinking that it *starts* something running, creates a thread, etc, when it's almost the opposite.